# Match where first characters in table value match query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I would like to be able to search in a table where sometimes the table has a full name, but sometimes it only has the initial letter. I can put any character after the initial letter, a * is shown below.

| Name | Info |
| --- | --- |
| A* | Foo |
| Bob | Bar |
| Mike | Boo |

If I search for Andrew, I'd like to be able to return A* as it's a possibility. I am trying something like this, but it's not working.

```
SELECT name, info FROM table WHERE
IF( RIGHT(name,1)="*" , CONCAT(LEFT(name,1) , "%") , name )
LIKE 'Andrew';
```

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you have the operands of the `like` operator reversed. The wildcard should be on the right hand operator:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  'Andrew' LIKE IF( RIGHT(name,1) = '*', CONCAT(LEFT(name, 1), '%'), name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just replace the `*` with `%` and use `like`:

```
where 'Andrew' like replace(name, '*', '%')
```